# Please capitalize the word “Emacs” on tour page

Tags: bug, status-completed

Here is “tour” page: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tour

It currently says:

> Emacs Stack Exchange is a question and answer site for those using,
>   extending, or developing the **emacs** text editor.

Emacs should be capitalized everywhere, it's name of our wonderful editor.

Comment: Oh, it seems there is already such request: http://meta.emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/251/site-description-has-an-extra-for-and-missing-capital-letter . However, since it's still not capitalized, let the requests accumulate :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completed it.  There was a second lowercase Emacs in the paragraph, changed it as well.